# How do I remove keywords in package listings?

Tags: listings

Sure enough, there is a `morekeywords` option, but suppose I need to remove some?

A case in point is Pascal, in which Writeln is not (strictly speaking) a keyword, but rather a predefined procedure.

I know I can redefine the style, but I am in the search for a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just realized there is a `deletekeywords` option!

Comment: deletekeywords={diff}, is not working for me. Any idea why that could be, or do I need to provide a reprex?